# Custom display of upper triangular matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a matrix 6 by 6 and I want to display upper triangular matrix without diagonal elements:

What I have done:

```
Rand_num = np.random.rand(6,6)
for i in range(0,6):
        for j in range(1,6):
                print Rand_num[i][j]
```

In my opinion an algorithm should be like:

```
for row = 1 to 6
    for col = (row+1) to 6
           print Rand_num[row][col]
```

How can I do it using Python?

The problem boils down to my task to fill up a matrix with elements that come from another list:
For instance have a Tmpelem list with 15 elements and I want them to assign to a new matrix (6 by 6) in this order that they create a triangular matrix without diagonal elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're fine with using NumPy as you did for your matrix creation, just use [`numpy.triu`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.triu.html)

```
In[126]: samp = np.random.rand(3, 3)

In[127]: np.triu(samp, k=1)
Out[127]: 
array([[ 0.        ,  0.77524531,  0.16391846],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.12625853],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]])
```

`k` denotes the diagonal under below which the rest shall be zeroed.

---

As per your edit, if you intend on *modifying* the upper triangular region of some existing matrix with a list of values, you can use [`numpy.triu_indices`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices.html) to get the correct indices, here using `(4,1)` to indicate a 4 by 4 matrix and one diagonal above the main.

```
In[142]: matr = np.arange(1, 17).reshape(4,4)

In[143]: matr
Out[143]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15, 16]])

In[144]: matr[np.triu_indices(4, 1)] = np.arange(100, 106)

In[145]: matr
Out[145]: 
array([[  1, 100, 101, 102],
       [  5,   6, 103, 104],
       [  9,  10,  11, 105],
       [ 13,  14,  15,  16]])
```

Comment: That's amazing! Than you so much for helping me out!

Answer (score -1):

it makes sense that numpy has a np.triu_indices as shown by Mitch

but looping can work too

```
A=np.zeros((6,6))

A
Out[31]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])

ulst = [i for i in range(1,16)]

ulst
Out[33]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]

ulst_gen = (i for i in ulst)

for i in range(6):
    for j in range(6):
        if j > i:
            A[i,j] = next(ulst_gen)

A
Out[36]: 
array([[  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.],
       [  0.,   0.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,  10.,  11.,  12.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  13.,  14.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  15.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.]])
```